# iOS Safari Sticky input at bottom unwanted white space

Tags: ios, html, scroll, safari, mobile-safari

So I have an input at the bottom of my page, positioned like so:

```
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
```

When I open the keyboard on iOS Safai, there is unwanted whitespace below the input. You can scroll up from it but it shouldn't be there.

[image: Screenshot]

The highlighting is from Safari Dev console, I've highlighted HTML, so the extra whitespace is not being caused by my HTML/CSS I think...

This does not happen on Android.

Any Help?

Comment: This seems to be also true for elements that does not have position fixed. Safari adds a whitespace at the bottom of body (not even a margin) whenever the software keyboard opens. Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

iOS safari does not respect `position: fixed` when the input has focus. What seems to be happening is that the element's position attribute is changed to `static`.

There are a couple aways around this, but the ultimate best answer for now would be to not use `fixed`.

Additional reading: https://medium.com/@im_rahul/safari-and-position-fixed-978122be5f29